# Figuring out the Solace version from a JAR file

Tags: java, executable-jar, solace-mq, solace

So I have a executable jar file. I need to figure out which Solace version did it use when it was built.

I can decompile and get the class files but that does not help me figure out the Solace version in that jar.

I also extracted the Manifets file from the JAR. The contents are

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

So i know the JAVA version but not the Solace version.

Any ideas or suggetsions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Generally the Solace API version is contained in the name of the Solace jar. For example: sol-jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar.

Internally within the Solace jar there will also be a manifest file in the META-INF directory which contains the version information. For example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_17-b02 (Oracle Corporation)

Name: com/solacesystems/jcsmp
Specification-Title: Solace Systems Messaging API for Java
Specification-Version: 7.0.0.63
Specification-Vendor: Solace Systems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: com.solacesystems.jcsmp
Implementation-Version: 7.0.0.63
Implementation-Vendor: Solace Systems, Inc.
```

Additionally, it is also possible for applications to get the Solace API version programmatically as follows:

```
JCSMPRuntime.onlyInstance().getVersion().getSwVersion()
```

So it would sort of depend on how your applications was packaged which of these methods would be most appropriate.